# C# Dynamic Console for debugging possible?

Tags: c#, debugging, console, devtools

I'm creating a program and i would really like to create a quick dev window into which i can type comands. I will try pseudo code what i'm trying to say.

```
Console
 User Types "Add player"
 Takes the string and searches a case statement which says
 Carry out these action on Form1
```

Is this possible to create a console which i can manipulate my C# Form program with?

The only answer i need is "Yes, to spawn a console do this........" i can work the rest out for myself. Or "no"

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Project + Properties, Application Tab.  Change Output Type to "Console Application".  Everything works as normal, plus a free console.  You'll want to spin up a thread to call Console.ReadLine()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Create a console application, add the necessary references and forms, then show your main form at the beginning. With this code you can change the content of a label on a form:

**Program.cs:**

```
static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
    var f = new Form1( );

    var t = new Thread( delegate( object form ) {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run( form as Form1 );
    } );

    t.Start( f );

    while ( true )
        f.SetText( Console.ReadLine( ) );

    t.Join( );
}
```

**Form1.cs:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1( ) {
        InitializeComponent( );
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;   // Note!!
    }

    public void SetText( string text ) {
        label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

I don't know the implications of setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false though.

Comment: You are breaking *two* very important UI thread rules.  This will gets the OP into a lot of trouble.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, that was my fear. Suggestions?

Comment: I recommend you delete your answer before it gets any more programmers into trouble.

Comment: @HansPassant maybe seeing the wrong way helps as well. Have you got any links explaining those UI thread rules?

Comment: Do NOT set the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false. leave it to the default. this is a critical issue if you are doing MT and can have knock on effects that Hans is referring to. Infact, the code supplies is doing that - why make it MT? There is no need to do so.